# Is it possible to get row number of a table in Snowflake without using the OVER function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to join a table on itself so need the row number. Is there a way to do it using arrays? I would prefer to do it without using windows functions.

[image]

The source data is column Order and Part. I want to calculate Column "Part Updated"

Pasting an updated table.

[image]

Thanks,

R

Comment: Why do you need a row number? You’ll probably get more helpful answers if you update your question with some sample data and show the result you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Nick, 

The original table has columns Order and Part. I am trying to create Part Updated.
Order Part Part Updated
A 1 NULL
A 5 1
A 7 5
A 13 7
A 25 13

I am trying to display the previous row value of Part column in Part Updated column.

Comment: Sorry could not format the table properly

Comment: Please update your question with all the additional information, don’t add it in comments. Include the data results (which you haven’t put in your comment) as well as the source data

Comment: So is the updated part number for a row always the maximum part number that is less than the row’s part number?

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry, it was just coincidental the the number in the Part Updated column is lower than the Part column. the number could be higher as well. Pasting an updated table

Comment: It seems there is zero reason not to use a Window Function, please explain this part.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to display the previous row value of Part column in Part Updated column.

Self join is not necessary. It could be achieved using [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) windowed function. For data as below:

```
Order Part PartUpdated 
A 1 NULL 
A 5 1 
A 7 5 
A 13 7
A 25 13
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, LAG(Part) OVER(PARTITION BY Order ORDER BY Part) AS PartUpdated
FROM tab
ORDER BY Order, Part;
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, Would the same be possible without using windows function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join a table to it's and don't want to use the exist keys, just assign a SEQ8() and join on that.

```
WITH has_seq AS (
    select *, seq8() as seq
    from table
)
SELECT a.one, a.two, b.three
FROM has_seq AS a
LEFT JOIN has_seq AS b
    ON a.seq = ​b.seq AND _some_other_things_ ​
```

if you are want to join again "all row after or before" you can as the sequent is increasing, but you cannot join to the "next" as there can be gaps.

BUT given your explaination, you need a WINDOW function. I would suggestion `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.order ORDER BY a.<insert order column here>) = 1`

I feel you need t explain why you cannot use a OVER function, given, it is what you need to use, and instead we can teach you how to use it, in the context you have.